# Different Behaviors - iOS 6 and iOS 7 - Confused

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, user-interface, storyboard

I'm trying to modify an iOS application (since the code is too complicated and too much, I cannot post it here).

I have created a new storyboard and assigned it as the Main Interface file, and built a whole new app ( new design + other new features ) in it.

It works great on iOS 7, but when I switch to iOS 6 in the simulator, the older interface and app is being loaded.

I have searched the AppDelegate and almost every place that was possible to load the interface programmatically, but I got no useful result.

Any suggestions on how and where should I look for the solution inside the Xcode project ?

Comment: do you created different storyboard for different version

Comment: No, I use one storyboard and I have set it to compile for all version the App is supported in.
I'm really confused about that !

Comment: do you tried reset your simulator or clean and build

Comment: Yes, Still no progress !

Even the launch screen is different, while I use Xcode Assets for launch images, and I'm sure that this image is not there !

Comment: Could you show us the part where you invoke the storyboard?

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't understand what you meant. Can you go a bit more clear ?

Comment: did you check same image name repeated in your project

Comment: Yeah, It's fine
Actually the main problem is that the XIB File is being loaded instead of the storyboard :(

Comment: This makes perfect sense. iOS 6 and iOS 7 have completely different interfaces, of course it will have the old iOS 6 interface if you load it up in iOS6 as iOS 6 doesn't know about the new APIs in iOS 7 to give it the iOS 7 look and feel. What makes you think it would look the same in iOS 6 with the flat UI as it does in iOS7?

Comment: @Popeye : U are getting me wrong !
I don't want it to load flat design on iOS 6 !
My main interface file is a storyboard ! Just one storyboard and it's all ! I have some other xib files in the project but I don't use them now, I used to use them for the interface before I create the storyboard.
The storyboard is being loaded successfully when I run iOS 7 Simulator, but it is not being loaded when I run iOS 6 Simulator ( It uses old xib files ) !!! Got me ?

Comment: I get you know, sorry miss read the question. Have you tried a clean build?

Comment: Yes , a lot of times , cleaning , reseting content , deleting derived data , everything !

Answer (score 1):

"When you switch to iOS6 in the simulator" - does this mean you are changing the OS version in the simulator menu? Each simulator has its own copy of the installed apps so your 6 simulator could have an old version installed.

You have to build and launch in the iOS6 simulator from Xcode - the various simulators can be chosen from the target / destination drop down in the top left of the screen.

You've confirmed that that isn't the issue, but I'll leave it there as it's useful information.

The initial interface is determined from a few places. In your project you've set the storyboard file - you have to check that it is the right name (case sensitive - there may be differences between the two).

Additionally, in previous versions of Xcode, you could specify either a main nib file or a main storyboard. It's possible that you've moved to a new version of Xcode and somewhere, somehow, the old nib file is still being referenced.

In this case open the info.plist file of your project and look for an entry called *Main Nib File* or similar. If this is present, you should delete it. You may need to open the info.plist as source code (right-click) to do this.

Comment: Of course I build and launch in the iOS simulator from Xcode.
Just to make sure that there's no caching problem, I deleted app from all the simulators with all OS versions, cleaned the Xcode project and reinstalled it. It didn't help !

Even the launch screen is different !!!

Comment: @Unkn0wn.Bit did you try resetting the simulators entirely? I've found Xcode can launch the wrong app if bundle identifiers match, even if product names are different.

Comment: Yeah, But just to make sure, I did it once again. No progress :(

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the "General" view from your target in Xcode? And what are the names of your storyboard and xib files?

Answer (score 0):

Rest your simulator via going  iOS Simulator->Rest Content and Setting.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this may help you :-

1) Ctrl-click on the project name at the root of the Groups & Files tree on the left side of your project window, and select "Reveal in Finder". In the Finder window, locate the Build folder and delete it;

2) The Groups & Files tree should have a "NIB Files" group near the bottom. Expand that group to see if OldXibName.xib is listed;

3) Do a search for OldXibName.xib in every volumn in your environment (Finder->File->Find...).

Courtsey:-RayNewbie

https://discussions.apple.com/message/12448077#12448077

Check your info plist too.